# Autosum column in csv using batch

Tags: csv, batch-file

I have created batch file to combine all csv file in folder. Below is my batch file code.

```
@ECHO OFF
SET first=y
SET newfile=Summary.csv
for %%F in (*.csv) do IF NOT %%F==%newfile% (
  if defined first (
    COPY /y "%%F" %newfile% >nul
    set "first="
  ) else (
    FOR /f "skip=1delims=" %%i IN (%%F) DO >> %newfile% ECHO %%i
  )
)
```

My question is, how do i add into the code if i want to add the autosum for every column?

Below is my example csv file after i run the batch file.

```
Name,A4 Used,A3 Used,Others
A,23,9,2
B,61,41,0
C,5,85,7
```

I need to create an autosum for every column like example below.

```
Name,A4 Used,A3 Used,Others
A,23,9,2
B,61,41,0
C,5,85,7
Total,89,135,9
```

Any idea guys?

Comment: You will need to use the `TOKENS` and `DELIMS` options of the `FOR /F` command.  You have 4 columns so the `TOKENS` option will be `TOKENS=1-4`.  Then use the comma as the delimiter.  You can then use `SET /A` command to add the numbers together.

Comment: Hi Squashman, thanks for the reply. Okay i will give it a try.

Comment: I should not that you cannot use the `COPY` command with your first file.  All files will need to be open and read with the `FOR /F` command.

Comment: Actually i am new with the batch file things. Can you provide me any article that i can refer to? Really appreciate your help.

Comment: @ashley, requests for off site resources, tutorials etc. are off topic here. Also, if you are using Windows, need to perform scripting operations, and don't have much experience with batch files, consider learning `PowerShell` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This task could be done with following commented batch code depending on contents of processed CSV files:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
rem Exit this batch file if current directory does not contain any CSV file.
if not exist *.csv goto EndBatch

rem The summary CSV file is created first in directory for temporary
rem files to avoid that outer FOR loop below tries to process also
rem the summary file. The summary file is created with header row.
set "NewFile=%TEMP%\Summary.csv"
echo Name,A4 Used,A3 Used,Others>"%NewFile%"

rem Make sure there is no summary CSV file in current directory
rem from a previous execution of this batch file in this directory.
del "Summary.csv" 2>nul

rem Initialize the environment variables for total sum of each column.
set "TotalColumn2=0"
set "TotalColumn3=0"
set "TotalColumn4=0"

rem The outer loop is executed for each CSV file in current directory.
rem The inner loop reads each CSV file line by line. The first line is
rem always skipped. Skipped are also empty lines and lines starting with
rem a semicolon. All other lines are split up into four substrings using
rem comma as separator (delimiter).

for %%I in (*.csv) do (
    for /F "usebackq skip=1 tokens=1-4 delims=," %%A in ("%%I") do (
        if not "%%D" == "" (
            set /A TotalColumn2+=%%B
            set /A TotalColumn3+=%%C
            set /A TotalColumn4+=%%D
            >>"%NewFile%" echo %%A,%%B,%%C,%%D
        ) else (
            del "%NewFile%"
            echo ERROR: A line in "%%I" has not four comma separated values.
            echo/
            pause
            goto EndBatch
        )
    )
)

rem Append to summary file the total sums and move the summary file
rem from temporary files directory to current directory. If that fails
rem unexpected, delete the summary file in temporary files directory.
>>"%NewFile%" echo Total,%TotalColumn2%,%TotalColumn3%,%TotalColumn4%
move "%NewFile%" "Summary.csv" >nul
if errorlevel 1 (
    del "%NewFile%"
    echo ERROR: Could not move Summary.csv to "%CD%".
    echo/
    pause
)

:EndBatch
endlocal
```

Please note the limitations of Windows command interpreter:

1. Arithmetic expressions can be done only with 32-bit signed integers which means the value range is limited from -2147483648 to 2147483647. There is no support for floating point arithmetic.
2. Command **FOR** interprets a sequence of delimiters as one delimiter on splitting up a line into substrings. So a row like `D,80,,20` in a CSV file results in loop variable `A` gets assigned `D`, loop variable `B` gets assigned `80`, loop variable `C` gets assigned `20` and loop variable `D` has nothing assigned. In this case the batch file exits with an error message.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `del /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `move /?`
- `pause /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Read also the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx).